# Synology / QNAP - remove drives and read from a basic enclosure?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, raid, nas

I recently had an old Windows 7 box fail on me that had 4 drives in it that I used for data backup. Luckily it was easy for me to remove these drives from the box and put them in a SATA to USB enclosure and read from them elsewhere. I am thinking of buying a QNAP or Synology NAS box - if i had one of those and if the box failed, would I be able to take the drives out and from them with a SATA to USB adapter the same way?

I am thinking of a simple raid 1 box so that the two drives are mirrored the same way. Thank you

Comment: The file system should certainly be recoverable. But normally it would be a case of connecting all the drives internally via SATA and accessing them directly in a Linux environment.What kind of USB enclosure do you have?

Comment: Nothing fancy, something similar to this: http://amzn.to/2eBvb1V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it should be possible, most of the Synology and QNAP NAS boxes are just cut down Linux computers using standard software libraries. But there are things to consider.

- The NAS will be using a Linux file system, e.g. EXT3 or EXT4, but the format is also specific to the `mdadm` software RAID utility. Some of the higher-end Synology models alternatively allow the use of BTRFS which is a more modern file system with its own support for RAID. Either way, if you're using Linux on your PC there isn't likely to be a problem but on Windows you would need specialist third-party tools.
- If you have disk encryption enabled then it will make things more complicated.
- Even though your disks are mirrored, you are best to connect *both* drives and mount as RAID 1 again as it will make accessing them much simpler. If you only have one USB enclosure then you obviously can't do that so you'd have to take extra steps to effectively rebuild the array.

Synology has a basic guide [here](https://www.synology.com/en-uk/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Storage/How_can_I_recover_data_from_my_DiskStation_using_a_PC) for recovering data using Ubuntu. I believe the process would be similar for QNAP devices.

Comment: BTRFS isn't as reliable on QNAP as EXT4.

Source: Qnap forums.

Comment: @Justin Goldberg: My post wasn’t advocating the use of BTRFS, I was simply mentioning it for completeness since it would involve a different recovery process